# What are the possible constellation-specific quest rewards from Observatory Quest?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

In Old School RuneScape's Observatory Quest, the reward you get depends on the constellation you observe through the telescope during the quest. Unfortunately, the first couple quest guides I found don't have a complete list, so I can't tell if I'll get unwanted experience from the reward.

Is there a complete list of the constellation-specific rewards for Observatory Quest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, such a list does exist.** I found a complete list in [this quest guide from March 2010](http://www.global-rs.com/quests/observatoryquest/) (no affiliation). It took some looking, as guides for the quest on most of the standard Old School help sites, such as 2007wiki and Zybez's 2007rshelp, do not contain such a list.

Here's the list:

> Aquarius: 25 Water runes
>   Aries: 875 Attack XP
>   Cancer: Amulet of protection
>   Capricorn: 875 Strength XP
>   Gemini: Black 2-handed sword and uncut sapphire
>   Leo: 875 Constituion [Hitpoints] XP
>   Libra: 3 Law runes
>   Pisces: 3 Cooked tunas and uncut sapphire
>   Sagittarius: Maple longbow
>   Scorpio: Weapon poison
>   Taurus: Super strength potion
>   Virgo: 875 Defence XP and uncut sapphire

Happy questing!